# Adding footer to a PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, header, footer

I want to get a PDF file, add a text to its footer or header save it back using PHP programming language.

Basically, I got a digital e-books library, I want to put a copyright text on each and every page of the pdf books.

Comment: Which PDF library you are using? Also, please post your code where you ar e getting issues.

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you are facing the problems??

Comment: My question is general, I haven't got any library yet. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Ofcourse possible. There are many libraries available like dompdf,fpdf,mpdf,tcpdf and many more...

Comment: @YashParekh Can you suggest any library which works well with Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the TCPDF Library and use the examples to learn

[Tcpdf.org](http://tcpdf.org)

[tcpdf header and footer default](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/)

Change the values in de header with your own values and save them in a database or something and later get the values from your database